# Why UV Map from files of Blender 2.79 not showing in Blender 3.0?

Tags: uv

I created a model in blender 2.79b. Unwrapped uv map there. Saved.
Then I opened in on blender 3.0. The uv map is gone, and I can't re-unwrap.
The uv just not appearing. But it should be there, because when I baked, it follow the older uv map.

Is this a matter of incompatibility?

File : [drive.google.com/file/d/16TRVNeN-_8xHLhUXCOEJqnFLBbsDbkmq/view?usp=sharing](http://drive.google.com/file/d/16TRVNeN-_8xHLhUXCOEJqnFLBbsDbkmq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: does it work with 2.9? Maybe share one of your unwrapped object so that we can test?

Comment: Not working either in 2.9. The UV editing menus is also different when opening this file. The normal is on top, this one at the bottom.

Comment: It worked for me. I opened ur shared file in both 2.9 and 2.79b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in Blender 2.79
[image]

and in BLender 2.93
[image]

actually Blender 2.8+ have different panel for UV editing And Image Editor, previous versions like 2.79 Used image editor menu for UVs

see the marked icons in the image of blender 2.93, above one is image editor and below one is UV editor

That's why you couldn't see ur uvs because the panel u have opened is Image Editor not UV Editor.

Comment: You're right! Thank you.